# Javascript form validation with dates, not working and form submitting anyway

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

```
function recurring_cb_fn(){
if( $("#recurring_yes").is(":checked") ){
    $("div#div_add_date").html("" +
    " <fieldset> " +
        " <legend> " +
            " Select Date of Venue " +
        " </legend> " +
        " <a href='#' id='add_date_fieldset' onclick='add_date()'>Add another date</a><br /><br /> " +
        " <input type='date' id='date_of_venue' name='date_of_venue[]' /> " +
            " <div class='add_date_for_venue'></div> " +
    " </fieldset> " );
}else if( $("#recurring_no").is(":checked") ){
    $("div#div_add_date").html("" +
    " <fieldset> " +
        " <legend> " +
            " Select Date of Venue: " +
        " </legend> " +
        " <input type='date' id='date_of_venue' name='date_of_venue' /> <br><br>" +
    " </fieldset> " );
}
}
function add_date(){
$("div#div_add_date").append("" +
" <fieldset> " +
    " <input type='date' id='date_of_venue' name='date_of_venue[]' /> " +
    " <a href='' id='remove_date_fieldset' name='remove_date_fieldset'><span class='el el-remove-circle'></span></a> " +
" </fieldset> " );
}
```

This is the function that I am using to allow a user to add multiple dates. I am using the name to store arrays in PHP, but have given them all the same ID to validate in javascript. The date must be in the future. This is my validation code:

```
var date_of_venue = $("input#date_of_venue").val();

if( validate_date(date_of_venue) ){
  $("span.el").remove();
  $("input#date_of_venue").before("<span class='el el-ok'></span>");
}else{
  $("span.el").remove();
  $("input#date_of_venue").before("Date must be in the future <span class='el el-remove'></span>");
}
```

And the function to check for date validity:

```
function validate_date(str) {
  var selectedText = str;
  var selectedDate = new Date(selectedText);
  var now = new Date();
  if (selectedDate < now) {
   alert("Date must be in the future");
   return false;
  }else{
   alert("Date is ok!");
   return true;
  }
```

The form is not checking for validity, and submitting the form anyway. 
Thanks!

Comment: **Same `id` is invalid** for any `html` page.. You need to have **unique `id`**'s in you page..

Comment: In addition, we have no idea how or if you're calling the validation code, what the HTML looks like, etc.

Comment: @GuruprasadRao - Yes, he *should* have unique ID's, but jQuery doesn't care. As far as jQuery is concerned, multiple ID's work like classes.

Comment: @PootieTang.. One or other way it is going to cause problem buddy.. Even though it works its not right way to do it..

Comment: @GuruprasadRao - no, it won't cause  problem. not for jquery at least. that's exactly my point. i'll prove it as soon as i finish this fiddle..

Comment: @Imran - Your code is fine. I had to make some assumptions since you didn't post the whole code, but I used your exact code in this fiddle and it works fine. see:  https://jsfiddle.net/6mhgwtk1/2/ - For future reference, you need to post all your code so we can see wherre the problem is, because it wasn't in anything you posted.

Comment: @GuruprasadRao - see the working example using OP's own code above

Comment: @Imran - Also note that user will have to enter the date in a specific format, ie 12/30/2015 or 12/30/2017 in order for `Date` to understand it. You're better off usin a datepicker, like the one in Jquery UI.

Comment: @PootieTang.. **jQuery does care** buddy.. Here is the **[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/f1o6u352/1/)** for you.. You can see that I had 3 `divs` with same `id` and I was trying to add `text` to all the 3 `divs`, but it got added only for the first `div`.. Had it been `class` , it would have added easily.. Even I used `.each`, still **jquery didn't care**.. :)

Comment: @GuruprasadRao - you saw my fiddle right? you saw op's code right? which part aren't you understanding... of course if you throw them all in the dom at the same time it will break but if you actually read the code, he is removing previous instances before adding more..

Comment: oh and **let me add some bold text too** for extra obnoxiousness..

Comment: @PootieTang You can definitely **add bold text to your comments**. **I don't care**.. But my point it just to say that **duplicate `id`'s doesn't work and its not according to `html` rules**.. If you see your first comment, you were saying that `jquery` doesn't care.. That's what I wanted to prove.. Now if you want to take it you take.. I ain't forcing you here for anything.. and am not here for mere arguments.. Have a nice time..

Comment: i will have the best time. it will be tremendous.

Comment: So when "add date" is clicked, a new date field is appended to the DIV. I tried putting same ID's and CLASSes for them to try to validate, but its working. How would i validate each date field to be in the future, ie. greater than current date?